# Ocultar estadisticas al compilar y ejecutar proyecto de Maven

Tags: java, maven, log

Buen dia compañeros del código, el motivo de esta pregunta es resolver una duda tengo el ide 11.3 de netbeans y el jdk 13.02 y en el momento de ejecutar cualquier proyecto en la consola se despliega toda esta info:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building mavenproject3 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ mavenproject3 ---
Hola Mundo!!
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.007 s
Finished at: 2020-11-18T12:51:35-05:00
Final Memory: 7M/30M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Lo que deseo es que solo me salga el mensaje o lo que tenga de texto en mi proyecto pero solo eso nada de fecha y todo eso, como lo puedo hacer por favor su ayuda me seria muy útil, buen  día.

Comment: ya intentaste con `-q`

Comment: y q hago con el -q, donde lo tengo q poner

Comment: al final de los parámetros que le pasa tu ide al maven. Si no sabes como hacer eso, igual te sugiero hacer otra pregunta para ello.